# Sublime Text editor: Is there a shortcut to select everything below this point and everything above this point

Tags: sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

Is there a shortcut to select all code below a certain point and above a certain point, if it's not already preset what is the best way of developing one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try Cmd + Shift + Up/Down or Ctrl + Shift + Up/Down on windows.

This will highlight / select all text above / below your current cursor location.

Answer (score 7):

Ctrl+Shift+Home to select everything above.

Ctrl+Shift+End to select everything below.

Comment: this works, thank you!